# Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I updated Android Studio to version 3.6 and after running my projects i got this error saying "Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
"

2020-02-28 14:44:25,568 [ 542460]   WARN - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Gradle sync failed: Cause: invalid type code: 85

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (1 s 245 ms) 
2020-02-28 14:44:25,568 [ 542460]   WARN - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState -
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.ProjectSetUpTask.onFailure(ProjectSetUpTask.java:120)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.executeImpl(ExternalSystemUtil.java:576)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.lambda$execute$0(ExternalSystemUtil.java:388)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.suspendIndexingAndRun(DumbServiceImpl.java:149)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:388)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$5.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:649)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:894)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:169)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:591)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:537)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:156)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.run(CoreProgressManager.java:408)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2020-02-28 14:44:25,649 [ 542541]   INFO - roid.tools.ndk.GradleWorkspace - Updating model took 0.039s 
2020-02-28 14:44:25,895 [ 542787]   INFO - ge.ExternalProjectsDataStorage - Save external projects data in 5 ms 
2020-02-28 14:44:26,052 [ 542944]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project 'C:\Users\himan\AndroidStudioProjects\Charging' ChargingKotlin2JvmCompilerArguments took 18 ms 
2020-02-28 14:44:26,078 [ 542970]   INFO - mponents.impl.stores.StoreUtil - saveProjectsAndApp took 213 ms 
2020-02-28 14:44:30,859 [ 547751]   INFO - ide.actions.ShowFilePathAction - 
Exit code 1

Comment: Please add screenshots and related code, if needed. Try to post your question with proper details.

Answer (score 5):

After trying whole day to solve this problem i got this solution 
i had jdk13 and after updating Android studio to 3.6.0, and with that groovy's latest version was also updated, on some websites it showed that groovy had some issues with jdk 9+ in latest version.
**So i downgraded jdk from jdk13 to jdk8 and problem got solved**

Comment: It is working for me. But now I have this type of error : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/appcompat/R$drawable;

Comment: Try removing cache and rebuild project. If not worked then close all projects also remove project from recent projects and then restart Android studio.

Comment: I have solved it by downgrade a classpath to 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'. Thanks for your valuable suggestion.

Comment: see: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle-jvm-selection.html to get the gradle version / jdk version compatibility matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Just my 2 cents here but I get this error when I put an apostrophe in my project name.

Answer (score 0):

It happens if you put some special characters in the Project Name while creating the project.

Answer (score 0):

Just try removing any special characters(if any) from your project name.
While making a project, if you put any special characters in your Project name, you get  this kind of error.
You won't be having a res folder and the gradle files would be misplaced.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally tapped codecleanup and then the errors got started. what i did was copy paste project gradle and gradle properties from some similar projects and then it was good to go.

I don't say it is perfect solution but it worked for me and may work for others as well